# List wrappers in JAXB MOXy

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am declaring a List object property with:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "...")
@XmlType
public class Test {
    private List<String> myList;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "myListWrapper")
    @XmlElement(name = "myList")
    public List<String> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

When an instance of this class with an empty list `myList` is marshalled, MOXy is not generating an empty wrapper `MyListWrapper`. However, JAXB RI would do it. The generated XML looks like this when using the RI:

```
<ns2:test xmlns:ns2="...">
    <myListWrapper/>
</ns2:intensionalSet>
```

Is there a way to obtain the same result with MOXy?

Comment: Did you try with required=true on the wrapper annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

This is a bug in the MOXy implementation of JAXB.  You can use the following link to track this issue:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363197

Comment: To save people clicking through, the bug is now fixed.