# jaxb annotations to suppress xmlns in soap response

Tags: jaxb, annotations

Initially i have all the fields without annotations in my POJO, those are showing great in Soap Response as

> `<fieldName>value</fieldName>`

Now i have a requirement to show the field even if the value is null;  then i added annotation for those fields as
@XmlElement( nillable = true)

Now in my soap response, it is showing as:

```
<fieldName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

I don't want to show xsi, xmlns, etc., in my soap response; how do i do that?

any link to show all annotations in jaxb at the field level, class level, etc.,?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all be aware, that

```
<fieldName/>
```

and

```
<fieldName xsi:nil="true"/>
```

are essentially different. The first will populate a String field with `""`. The latter will populate it with `null`.

Unfortunately, the behaviour of XmlAdapters for fields with value `null` is dependent on the JAXB implementation - the JDK implementation will not call the Adapter at all.

One Solution would be using `@XmlAccessorType(PROPERTY)` and implement the getter to return `""` instead of `null`.

[Eclipselink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) seems to be able to handle it.

I found a similar discussion here: [XmlAdapter not working as expected in JAXB RI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012100/xmladapter-not-working-as-expected-in-jaxb-ri)