# Represent null value as empty element in xml jaxb using quarkus extensions

Tags: apache-camel, jaxb, quarkus, moxy

I'm am using eclipse MOXy to represent null values in xml, like it is described here:
[Represent null value as empty element in xml jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366054/represent-null-value-as-empty-element-in-xml-jaxb)

I like to get rid of this dependency and just use extensions of quarkus like camel and standard jaxb to do so to be able to use quarkus native.
But unfortunately I can't find anything on that.

I am totally aware that this representation is not standard, but the consumer of the xml files insists on that.

Does somebody know If there is a way with quarkus or standard jaxb to represent null value as empty element in xml ?
Or do newer Moxy versions work with quarkus native.

For expample I ruled out using XmlAdapter as null values do not even get to be applied. ( [XmlAdapter not working as expected in JAXB RI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012100/xmladapter-not-working-as-expected-in-jaxb-ri) )